# vissim com with python interface

Tags: python, ptv-vissim

I am using vissim com and trying to integrate python. After I load, the simulation in vissim starts. But when I add a link and give other commands GetMultiAttValues etc (last 3 commands of code given ), it doesn't change anything and does not give the data of the command ( doesn't add links or give details). My code is here given below.

```
Vissim = com.Dispatch("Vissim.Vissim")
file="D:\Simulation\MLK2.1rough.inpx"
Vissim.LoadNet(file)
Vissim.Simulation.RunContinuous()
k=Vissim.Net.Links
Vissim.Net.Links.AddLink(42, 'LineString(0 30, 200 200)', [3.5, 3.5])
print(k.GetMultiAttValues('Name'))
print(Vissim.Net.Links.ItemBykey(1).AttValue('Length2D'))
```

Comment: I don't think the `RunContinuous` function is blocking, and you can't add a link while the simulation is running.

Comment: I tried commenting out the Runcontinuous function and now it gives name attributes for this command ```print(Vissim.Net.Links.GetMultiAttValues('Name'))``` But for ```print(Vissim.Net.Links.ItemBykey(5).AttValue('Length2D'))``` , it says com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None) .

Comment: Is everything working as expected now?

Comment: 1. for every print command I give, vissim starts newly for output of my new command.  and 2. ```print(Vissim.Net.Links.ItemBykey(5).AttValue('Length2D'))``` , this command gives``` com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None) ``` error but the 5 key is present in the vissim link details.

Comment: It is working. I used k instead of K, a type error in 'ItemByKey' .Thanks very much

Comment: Ah, Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Most of the Vissim community exchanges happen on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2524087). So you might get faster answers there. Or you could also contact PTV's technical support.